# $\int _ { 0 } ^ { L } \left\{ \left( \int _ { 0 } ^ { x } f ( y ) d y \right) \left( \int _ { 0 } ^ { x } g ( z ) d z \right) \right\} d x$

Tags: integration

As in the title,

What I wanna do is

$\int _ { 0 } ^ { L } \left\{ \left( \int _ { 0 } ^ { x } f ( y ) d y \right) \left( \int _ { 0 } ^ { x } g ( z ) d z \right) \right\} d x$

Here, functions f and g are arbitrary ones, x is a variable, and L is a constant number.

I can do this numerically. But It takes so much computation costs.

Therefore, I'd like to convert this formula to a simpler form before doing numerical computation. (I think the integral by parts can be a key but I have no idea how/where I should apply it)

Are there any clever ways to do this?

Comment: What numerical algorithm are you using? The formula is already "simple".

Comment: I'm using the Gaussian quadrature. But, I need much more matrix computations than those I needed for solving just normal integral such as int(f(x),0,L).

Comment: I don't see the problem, It's a single for loop unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @SinwooJeong It shouldn't take meaningfully longer than a single integral. Going from $\int_0^x \ldots$ to $\int_0^{x+dx} \ldots$ just requires adding one evaluation of $\ldots$ to the former...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very straightforward as it is... For general functions $f,g$ there is no way of simplifying the expression. From the numerical point of view, taking a regular decomposition of $[0,L]$ and some numerical quadrature $\int_0^L h(x) dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n w_i f_i$, you just have to implement the expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(w_i \left(\sum_{j=1}^{i} w_j f_j\right)  \left(\sum_{j=1}^{i} w_j g_j\right) \right)
$$